# Can a wind rose chart be created in ECharts?

Tags: javascript, echarts

A very common chart in weather and maritime is a wind rose chart.

Is it possible in echarts to create one of these? It has segmented bands of speed and various sectors per 0-360 directions. See sample chart below or a example of how Plotly gets it done in their library: https://plotly.com/javascript/wind-rose-charts/

If so, what would the code look like? I attempted to alter this sample (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-polar-stack-radial), but it seems in order to get the segmented bands we need to use `category` in the `angleAxis` which is not correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this work. I found this [chart](https://www.makeapie.com/editor.html?c=xa-f-aLlNA) (and [similar](https://www.makeapie.com/editor.html?c=xylqCbh7u)) on the [Echarts Gallery](https://www.makeapie.com/) but gallery takes a very long time to load or not available on some days but today i'm lucky:

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));

var legendName = [
  "0.0-0.2 m/s",
  "0.3-1.5 m/s",
  "1.6-3.3 m/s",
  "3.4-5.4 m/s",
  "5.5-7.9 m/s",
  "8.0-10.7 m/s",
  "10.8-13.8 m/s",
  "13.9-17.1 m/s",
  "17.2-20.7 m/s",
  "20.8-24.4 m/s",
  "24.5-28.4 m/s",
  "28.5-32.6 m/s",
  ">32.6 m/s"
]
var vocs = [
  "0.3 mg/m³",
  "0.4 mg/m³",
  "0.3 mg/m³",
  "0.3 mg/m³",
  "0.5 mg/m³",
  "0.23 mg/m³",
  "0.2 mg/m³",
  "0.7 mg/m³",
  "0.6 mg/m³",
  "0.2 mg/m³",
  "0.1 mg/m³",
  "0.1 mg/m³",
  "0.6 mg/m³",

];

var option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    textStyle: {
      color: '#fff'
    }
  },
  color: ["#0001F7", "#00B8FE", "#00FFFF", "#00FF68", "#BEFE00", "#FFFF00", "#FFA800", "#E10100"],
  angleAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ["北", "北东北", "东北", "东东北", "东", "东东南", "东南", "南东南", "南", "南西南", "西南", "西西南", "西", "西西北", "西北", "北西北"],
    boundaryGap: false, //标签和数据点都会在两个刻度之间的带(band)中间
    axisTick: {
      show: false //是否显示坐标轴刻度
    },
    splitLine: {
      show: true,
      lineStyle: {
        // color:"black"
      },
    },
    axisLabel: {
      show: true,
      interval: 1, //坐标轴刻度标签的显示间隔，在类目轴中有效
    },
  },
  radiusAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    axisLabel: {
      show: false
    },
    axisTick: {
      show: false //是否显示坐标轴刻度
    },
    axisLine: {
      show: false //是否显示坐标轴轴线
    },
  },
  polar: {},
  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    data: [17, 2, 18, 4,
      2, 3, 4, 6,
      1, 6, 3, 4,
      2, 3, 4, 6
    ],
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: legendName[0],
    stack: 'a'
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: [7, 12, 13, 2,
      2, 3, 4, 6,
      1, 2, 3, 2,
      2, 3, 4, 6
    ],
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: legendName[1],
    stack: 'a'
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: [10, 12, 13, 4,
      2, 13, 14, 26,
      11, 12, 23, 34,
      12, 33, 34, 32
    ],
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: legendName[2],
    stack: 'a'
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: [10, 2, 13, 2,
      2, 3, 4, 6,
      1, 2, 3, 2,
      2, 3, 4, 6
    ],
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: legendName[3],
    stack: 'a'
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: [10, 2, 13, 4,
      2, 3, 4, 6,
      1, 2, 3, 4,
      1, 2, 3, 1
    ],
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: legendName[4],
    stack: 'a'
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: [10, 2, 13, 2,
      2, 3, 4, 6,
      1, 2, 3, 2,
      1, 2, 3, 1
    ],
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: legendName[5],
    stack: 'a'
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: [10, 2, 13, 4,
      2, 3, 4, 6,
      1, 2, 3, 4,
      2, 3, 4, 2
    ],
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: legendName[6],
    stack: 'a'
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: [1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0
    ],
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: legendName[7],
    stack: 'a'
  }],
  legend: {
    show: true,
    data: legendName,
    width: 500, //根据宽度调整换行
  }
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.9.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 600px;height:600px;"></div>
```